# MySQL: Best way to store MAC addresses?

Tags: mysql, mac-address

What's the best field type to use to store MAC addresses in a MySQL database? Also, should it be stored with a certain separator (colon or dash) or should it be stored without a separator?

Comment: define 'best'. What do you intend to do with the data?

Comment: It's for an inventory system. I suppose my question is "what do most people do?".

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I will do some experimenting.

Answer (score 32):

use bigint unsigned (8 bytes) then you can:

```
select hex(mac_addr) from log;
```

and

```
insert into log (mac_addr) values (x'000CF15698AD');
```

Comment: so you can also put Infiniband GUIDs :-)

Comment: In this example, the hex() function would return : CF15698AD, which is not a mac address. When you run __select  hex(mac_addr)__, the output is not always in 12 characters as you would expect.

Comment: @jon black MAC addresses, for Ethernet devices anyway. are six bytes in length.  Should unsigned INT(6) work?  Is unsigned BIGINT(8) being suggested instead of unsigned INT(6) solely to support infiniband GUIDs?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/217529). Generally, CHAR(12) is good but details depend on your needs. Or just use PostgreSQL, which has a built-in macaddr type.

Comment: First time I've seen mention of PostgreSQL macaddr type

Comment: careful: PostgreSQL macaddr type does not support 8-byte MACs

Comment: PostgreSQL support 8-bytes MACs type macaddr8 since version 10. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-MACADDR8

Answer (score 1):

Given that MySQL does not support user defined extensions, nor does it seem to support arbitrary extensions or plugins (just for storage engines), your best bet is to store it as a CHAR(17) as an ASCII string in standard notation (e.g., with colon separators), or a small BLOB and store the bytes directly.  However, the string notation is going to be more friendly for most applications.

You may want to pair it with a trigger that validates that it is a MAC address, since that is really the only way to enforce data validity without support for custom types.